# Replace / Update "&" in a URL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem in a big table in `SQL Server`. The correct shape of my `URLs` is (note the `&`):

```
https://na13.salesforce.com/apex/ConvertLead?&cid=&lid=00Qa000001NW0XY&cmid=701a0000002MxZ5
```

But in the table I have a lot of this kind of  URLs (without `&`):

```
https://na13.salesforce.com/apex/ConvertLead?cid=lid=00Qa0000019rw6wcmid=701a0000002MxYg
```

I need insert the `&` in the URLs without it.

Comment: Do all the target values start with `"https://na13.salesforce.com/apex/ConvertLead"`, or should the replace work for *any* url?

Comment: I just want to insert the &

Comment: It is not possible without knowing where i have to insert `&` in existing `URL`

Comment: What are the difference url parameters that you have? e.g. cid, lid, ... is this a known set?

Comment: @alvaro yes, but answer the question: do all your urls start with the same path?

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE (url, 'ConvertLead?', 'ConvertLead?&')
```

REPLACE([columnname],[valuetolookfor],[valuetoreplaceitwith])

In an update :

```
UPDATE tablename SET url = REPLACE (url, 'ConvertLead?', 'ConvertLead?&')
```